# How to configure SQL Server to show the Results in a Specific Culture format?

Tags: sql-server

How do i configure the sql server to show the query results in a specific culture format.?

For example a numeric value in english format is 123.456.
The same in turkish format is 123,456.

how do i make this change?. Not only for the numeric type, for all data types?

Comment: You can't configure SQL Server to do that. This is a job for your App where the data is presented.

Comment: If it is  query you can use FORMAT.Though it is just  for  Numeric  and  Date and Time

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have any UI. SQL Server Management Studio has a *minimal* UI but is mainly intended for ad-hoc access. If you have UI concerns, put them *in the UI that you're building*, not in the server which should be storing *data*, not *presentation*.

Comment: numeric data does not have any format ! It is how you want to present it in any format that you want. And presentation and formatting of your data should be done in your applicaton or reporting tool. Not in SQL Server. SQL Server is for storing of data. And the numeric data is stored in some internal binary format not stored in any particular format in the table like english or turkish

Comment: @Squirel  The decimal separator in Turkish is Comma. So how the turkish people write a decimal value in sql server management studio? DECLARE '@Number' AS DECIMAL SET '@Number' = ? 123.456 or 123,456

Answer (score 0):

You can use format function. Like this:

```
declare @a decimal (18, 4) = 1234.1234

select format (@a, '##.##', 'tr-TR')

select format (@a, '##.##', 'en-US')
```

Comment: How do i do this if my Numeric data is in turkish format?

Comment: What do you mean it is in Turkish format? Decimal is decimal!

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem, because the configuration Region was "España", and the numbers have the character "," to separate decimals, but I needed the "." to separate decimals.

1. I had to change the Region To Mexico
2. I had to install the package to language Español(Mexico).
3. I had to select Español (Mexico) into the combo box "Windows Languaje"

then I need to restart but,I had the same problem, here are the last steps.

4. Directly in control panel Go to Regino
5. Click "Change date format ..."
6. In the tab "Administrative", click into the button "Copy Configuration" (start session screen..), and opened a new windows.
7. Click into the check box, "start session screen and system account)
8. Finaly Restar the server